# How to solve the segmentation fault and UI crash issue during the QProcess

Tags: python, linux, pyqt5, segmentation-fault, qprocess

I'm currently developing a MultiThreading window form application using Python that functions by executing `QProcess` commands via buttons and signaling start and end with a record that is displayed on the window. However, it always crashes due to unresponsiveness or segmentation faults in a Linux environment, whereas it works fine in a Windows environment. My task takes a long build time, about 8 minutes on average, so I use dummy data to simulate the long run time. Where `waitForFinished(-1)` is to ensure that the next task is executed only after the current task is completed.

I have used `-X faulthandler` to locate the position of the Segmentation fault.

Environment Version:

```
OS: Linux, Python: 3.6.9, PyQt5: 5.15.6
```

Segmentation Fault:

```
Thread 0x00007fde5fffe700 (most recent call first):
File .../test.py line 27 in run
File .../test.py line 107 in process_single
File .../test.py line 51 in run

Thread 0x00007fde63ffe700 (most recent call first):
File .../test.py line 27 in run
File .../test.py line 107 in process_single
File .../test.py line 51 in run

Current thread 0x00007fdfd245f740(most recent call first):
File .../test.py line 40 in process_output
File .../test.py line 132 in <module>
```

My code:

```
import sys
import threading
from functools import partial
from queue import Queue
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *

class Job(QObject):
    task_msg = pyqtSignal(str)
    task_started = pyqtSignal()
    task_finished = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, job_build_cmd):
        super().__init__()
        self.job_build_cmd = job_build_cmd  
        self.task_process = None

    def run(self):
        self.task_process = QProcess()
        env = QProcessEnvironment.systemEnvironment()
        env.insert('PATH', '/usr/bin:'+env.value('PATH'))
        self.task_process.setProcessEnvironment(env)
        self.task_process.readyReadStandardOutput.connect(self.process_output)
        self.task_process.finished.connect(lambda exitcode: self.process_finished(exitcode))
        self.task_process.start('bash', ['-c', self.job_build_cmd])
        self.task_process.waitForFinished(-1)

    def process_finished(self, exitCode):
        self.process_output()
        self.task_finished.emit()
        if self.task_process is not None:
            if self.task_process.isOpen():
                self.task_process.close()
            self.task_process.deleteLater()
            self.task_process = None
        
    def process_output(self):
        if self.task_process is not None and self.task_process.isOpen():
            line_data = bytes(self.task_process.readAllStandardOutput()).decode('utf-8', errors = 'replace').strip()
            for line in line_data.splitlines():
                self.task_msg.emit(f'{str(line)}')

class WorkThread(QThread):
    def __init__(self, process_single, t_id):
        super().__init__()
        self.process_single = process_single
        self.t_id = t_id
        
    def run(self):
        self.process_single(self.t_id)

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.job_queue = Queue()
        self.work_threads = []
        self.stop_job = False
        self.lock_get_job = threading.Lock()
        self.process = []
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 100, 100)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        self.startbtn = QPushButton('Start')
        self.startbtn.clicked.connect(self.run_build)
        layout.addWidget(self.startbtn)

        centralWidget = QWidget()
        centralWidget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)

    def run_build(self):
        self.startbtn.setEnabled(False)
        tasks = {
            'Job 1': 'for i in $(seq 1$((RANDOM%101+50))); do len=$(($RANDOM % 100 + 30)); echo "Random text $i: $(tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 </dev/urandom | head -c $len)"; sleep 0.$((RANDOM % 10 + 1)); done; exit $((RANDOM % 2))'
        }
        for name, cmd in tasks.items():
            job = Job(cmd)
            job.task_msg.connect(print)
            self.job_queue.put(job)
            self.process.append(job)
            job.task_finished.connect(partial(self.sync_task_finish, job))
        self.create_worker()
            
    def create_worker(self):
        self.num_of_worker = 2
        self.work_threads =[]
        for id in range(self.num_of_worker):
            worker = WorkThread(self.process_single, id)
            self.work_threads.append(worker)
            worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)
            worker.start()
            
    def process_single(self, t_id):
        while not self.stop_job:
            try:
                with self.lock_get_job :
                    if not self.job_queue.empty():
                        job = self.job_queue.get()
                    else:
                        break
                if job is not None:
                    job.task_finished.connect(self.release_process)
                    job.run()
            except Exception as e:
                if job is not None:
                    with self.lock_get_job:
                        self.job_queue.task_done()

    def release_process(self):
        with self.lock_get_job :
            self.job_queue.task_done()

    def sync_task_finish(self, job):
        with self.lock_get_job :
            if job in self.process:
                self.process.remove(job)
            if len(self.process)==0:
                self.job_finish()
    
    def job_finish(self):
        if self.job_queue.empty():
            self.startbtn.setEnabled(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mainWindow = MainWindow()
    mainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I have attempted to use `deleteLater` and `close` to release resources, as well as employing `Lock` to try to solve the problem, `QMetaObject.invokeMethod` and `@pyqtSlot` to replace `partial`,but none of these solutions have been effective.

I have reduced unnecessary UI displays to ensure the integrity of `QProcess` and the process of resource release.
I hope it can execute all tasks in the queue properly without the UI crashing.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to reduce it to a [mcve] of your problem.  Your current code includes much that is peripheral to your problem - a minimal sample normally looks similar to a good unit test: only performing one task, with input values specified for reproducibility.

Comment: @TobySpeight , This is where I removed unnecessary UI displays to ensure a complete QProcess program and release of features.

Comment: @GuanzT Your current example has numerous basic coding errors which means it cannot be tested. Please therefore fix all those errors and ensure you post a proper [mre].

Comment: @ekhumoro Currently, only the start and end of QProcess and the construction of MultiThreading related to issue retention are preserved.

Comment: @GuanzT I see that you've now provided a test-case that runs. However, on my Linux system (using Python-3.11.7 with Qt-5.15.12 and PyQt-5.15.10) it never crashes unless the window is closed before the jobs have completed. The crash on close can be fixed by terminating the processes in a close-event handler on the main window: `def closeEvent(self, event): for job in self.process: job.task_process.terminate()` (if terminate doesn't work, use `kill()` instead). If the test crashes for you *before* closing, this could be because you are using an obsolete version of Python (3.6 EOL 2021).

Comment: @ekhumoro 
My Python version (python-3.6.9) cannot be changed, and under Windows (using Python-3.6.8, PyQt5-5.15.6, PyQt5-Qt5-5.15.2) it works normally without any segmentation faults or UI unresponsiveness. Currently, the command only simulates long-duration output of a large amount of text. In practice, it will record the build process through commands like `source` and `mkdir` and display it on the UI.

Comment: I' ve tried multiple variations of this, but none of them seem to work. Under the guidance of `faulthandler`, it indicates that there is an issue with `QProcess`. I have also attempted to add resource release, but the segmentation fault and UI unresponsiveness still occur. The timing of these issues sometimes happens shortly after startup, and sometimes towards the end of the overall build.

Comment: @GuanzT The problem is very likely to be related to garbage-collection, which can sometimes be unpredictable since Python does not guarantee the order in which objects are deleted. This means Qt may sometimes try to delete the C++ part of a PyQt object that has already been deleted by Python, causing a crash. The unpredictability often shows up when the same code is run with different Python/PyQt versions, or on different machines. Try commenting out all lines that try to delete the thread/job objects or remove them from lists: i.e. keep everything alive until the entire build has run.

Comment: @ekhumoro I have attempted to comment out `task_process.close()`, `task_process.deleteLater()`, and `worker.finished.connect(worker.deleteLater)`, but the problem persists. The UI crash sometimes occurs just as the build starts, when the first job is still executing.

Comment: @GuanzT You must also comment out `self.process.remove(job)`. But if the problem still persists after that, it shouldn't be too difficult to find the cause. You just need to remove parts of your test script little by little until you have the absolute minimum needed to reproduce the problem. Start by removing all the queue/locking code, then remove the signals one by one, and so on. If you keep going like that, eventually you must reach a point where the problem disappears. Your test script is quite short, so it won't take long to zero in on the specific cause.

Comment: @GuanzT PS: I have now tested your script in a venv on Linux with Python 3.6, 3.7, 3.8 & 3.9 and I still cannot reproduce the problem. How exactly did you install PyQt5 on your system? Was it by using your distro's official packages, via pip, or did you compile it yourself? If it wasn't via pip, it might be worth setting up a venv and installing PyQt5 into that to see if you can still reproduce the problem (note that you will probably need to upgrade pip in order to do this).

Comment: @ekhumoro 
My Linux environment is Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS, and PYQT5 was installed via pip. I have tried using GPT to find the problem, but the responses always suggest that it's an issue with the QProcess lifecycle. The command is only simulating long-duration output of a large amount of text, but in reality, it is displaying the log process on the TextBrowser UI.

Comment: @GuanzT GPT just spews out random mashups of text from unevaluated sources. I have demonstrated that this problem *cannot be reproduced* using the current test script in the question with Python-3.6.9 and PyQt5-5.15.6 on Linux. The only reasonable conclusion is that this issue is caused by your specific system setup (since standard long-term support for Ubuntu-18.04 ended in May 2023 and for Python-3.6 in Dec 2021). It should be possible to identify the issue more precisely using the approach suggested above, but if you won't put in the effort to do that, I cannot help any further.